# How to "inject" data from our backend (razor) into AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, razor

We have variables in our backend that we want to display on our frontend after various calculations and database queries.

We use the Razor templating engine. Our Angular is instantiated in a .cshtml file.

We thought of two ways:

1. Use a global variable called "inejcted" and access it from our Angular services.
2. Have inject the data into attributes of certain HTML elements.

None of the ways seems like a good way to do it. The first is bad because we're involving non-Angular related code in our JS, as global vars. The second might become dirty and flooded with such injections all over the application over time.

I'm pretty sure that this has been encountered many times before. What would be the best way to "inject" data to our Angular application and then process that information in our modules?

Comment: You can have some Razor partial views linked to methods on your backend controller and call them using ajax request from your angular app.....

Comment: Why not use WebAPI and publish the data as an api endpoint?  Then angular can request the data when it is ready to consume it, rather than it being generated during the page load even if it isn't needed.  This is the most canonical way to handle this kind of exchange...

Comment: In general, you should, as much as possible, avoid having two template engines (one server, one client).  It is much more efficient (and user friendly) to use one framework.